# Connection must be valid and open error in visual studio

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, mariadb

I'm trying to show in my datagridview all the registers from a mariadb database, but when I start the code, it appears the errror "Connection must be valid and open error", the code is [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pc95.png):

I'll be glad if somebody can help me :)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), post the code itself. I suspect your issue is because you are calling `ExecuteNonQuery()` after calling execute reader. This is redundant. You should also use `using` blocks to ensure your objects are disposed of correctly

Comment: @Enzo GarethD gave a good answer, you can try it and update if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your code. Firstly you don't associate your connection object with your command object, instead of

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM encomendas");
```

It should be

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM encomendas", bdcon);
```

Also, there is no need to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. It is also advisable to use `using` blocks on objects that implement `IDisposable` to ensure they are disposed of correctly, so your full code might be:

```
var datatable = new DataTable();
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring"))
using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM encomendas", connection ))
{
    connection.Open()'
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
         datatable.Load(reader);
    }
}
// Bind to your grid view
```

With that being said, if you are looking to fill a DataTable then [`MySqlDataAdapater()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataAdapter.htm) is the simplest approach:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM encomendas", "ConnectionString"))
{
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
// Bind to your grid view
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete MysqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("") row and
try it

```
        using (var sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM encomendas", bdcon))
        {
            MySqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(read);

        }
```

try it

Answer (score 0):

Your object of `MysqlCommand` must have association with your object `MysqlConnection`. Obviously your cmd has no business with bdcon, that is the reason why it says "Connection must be valid and open error" when you call the method ```cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().
Here is a similar snippet.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
//or
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sql text", sqlConnection);
```